# How to divide column sum by row sum in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a data frame called df. It looks like this.

| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 |

I want to sum up the columns and divide the sum of the columns by the sum of the rows.
So for example:
row 1, column 0: (1+4+7)/(1+2+3)
row 2, column 0: (1+4+7)/(4+5+6)

so on and so forth.

so that my final result is like this.

| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2.5 | 3 |
| 0.8 | 1 | 1.2 |
| 0.5 | 0.625 | 0.75 |

How do I do it in python using pandas and dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it this way:

```
import numpy as np
a = df.to_numpy()
b = np.divide.outer(a.sum(0),a.sum(1)) 
# divide is a ufunc(universal function) in numpy.
# All ufunc's support outer functionality
out = pd.DataFrame(b, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
```

output:

```
     0      1     2
0  2.0  2.500  3.00
1  0.8  1.000  1.20
2  0.5  0.625  0.75
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the underlying numpy array:

```
a = df.to_numpy()
out = pd.DataFrame(a.sum(0)/a.sum(1)[:,None],
                   index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
```

output:

```
     0      1     2
0  2.0  2.500  3.00
1  0.8  1.000  1.20
2  0.5  0.625  0.75
```